# How to check if .hdmp file was sent to Microsoft (WER)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-error-reporting, minidumps

How can one tell if a `.hdmp` file (or other dumps) has been sent to Microsoft as part of WER (Windows Error Reporting) on Windows 10?

My understanding is that when an application crashes and/or becomes unresponsive an `.hdmp` file is created within `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp`, sent to Microsoft, and subsequently deleted leaving no trace.

For example, if I open up WER event folders of which have been sent/reported to Microsoft (located within `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\`) I can only locate `.wer` files of which contain only generic information about the report, when opening the `.wer` files in a text editor I can find no references (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> "`.hdmp`" within the opened `.wer` files) to `.hdmp` files, would that mean one was not generated/sent to Microsoft associated with these WER events?

Comment: Does this Microsoft Article help you?  ..............   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/windows-error-reporting

Comment: @John Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that article doesn't provide any information with regards to when a WER event will result in .hdmp generation, nor information pertaining to identifying if a particular WER event resulted in the generation of a .hdmp file (and subsequently sending .hdmp to Microsoft servers). This post includes some useful information about .hdmp files, where they're (temporarily) saved, etc. but doesn't quite answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540110/how-do-you-get-windows-error-reporting-wer-to-save-memory-dumps-for-hangs